# This update query won't update record

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update

I made a simple form to insert, delete, and update records.

my edit (UPDATE) doesn't work and i don't know why.

Here is some code for edit funciton.

```
if (isset($_GET['edit'])) 
{
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nieuweprijs" placeholder="vul nieuwe prijs in">
    <input type="submit" name="submitnieuweprijs" value="verzenden"><form>

}


if (isset($_POST['submitnieuweprijs'])) 
{
    $nieuweprijs = Safesql($_POST['nieuweprijs']);
    $id = Safesql($_GET['edit']);   
    if(!$mysqli->query("UPDATE prijzen SET prijs= '".$nieuweprijs."' WHERE id='".$id."'")){ echo $mysqli->error;}
    Laden(0);
}
```

Comment: What you have shown isn’t even valid PHP code. You can not just switch from PHP to HTML tags like that.

Comment: Probably after submitting your url doesn't contain edit parameter.(which you store your ID)

Comment: @D.Dimitrov Sorry i am a noob in coding, you mean i change the submit to a href button with index.php?...something...

Comment: I mean if you have URL like http://localhost/index.php?edit=2 - your form is displayed, after submit (your form action is index.php) - your edit parameter is gone, so you're not updating anything.

Comment: Welcome. As @misorude stated this is invalid PHP code (and HTML too `<form>` should be `</form>`) You could turn on `error_reporting` to see any errors. Also, don't blindly assume that `$_GET['edit']` exists, _make sure_ it does before you execute your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php    
   if (isset($_GET['edit']))

   {
?>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="id" value="<?=$id;?>">
    <input type="text" name="nieuweprijs" placeholder="vul nieuwe prijs in">
    <input type="submit" name="submitnieuweprijs" value="verzenden"><form>

<?php }
if (isset($_POST['submitnieuweprijs']))

{
    $nieuweprijs = Safesql($_POST['nieuweprijs']);
    $id = Safesql($_GET['id']);   
    if(!$mysqli->query("UPDATE prijzen SET prijs= '".$nieuweprijs."' WHERE id='".$id."'"))
      { echo $mysqli->error;}
       Laden(0);
    }
} 
?>
```

`$id` is the value obtained from the query when editing data, you cannot update without ID definition or else

Comment: Thank you it works! only in the inputfield "id" there is an error undifined index id